Who loves whom in “Jane has this illusion that John is in love with her”?
At first glance, what would a native English speaker think the following meant?

Jane has this illusion that John is in love with her.

In a word, does 'her' refer to Jane or another woman?
I think reflexive pronoun 'herself' would clear out any ambiguousness.

Quite apart from the fact that what Jane thinks is mistaken, it's also ambiguous whether "her" refers to Jane, or to some other woman mentioned earlier (in the full context, which isn't available here). And that's obviously the reason for raising the question, so the "truth value" of Jane's thoughts are irrelevant anyway.

I’m voting to close this question because it lacks sufficient context.

@MichaelHarvey My question is focused on 'at first glace as a native speaker': what aspect of image of meaning arises

Native speakers don't normally encounter utterances without context in the rarified display case of a language forum. They encounter them in conversation and in books. So @$)@$*_  tired of this sort of question.  It's not that English is the only language in the world that runs on context.

"mistaken illusion" is pleonastic BTW. "mistaken idea" is the usual collocation.

Your question is probably going to be closed because it lacks context. Almost any sentence without context runs the risk of being ambiguous, the OP has to either tell us what was mentioned earlier in the story or explain why they are asking this question. Is this taken from a multiple choice question from a school textbook or online quiz? Did someone tell you the answer is "we don't know" and you want to check whether this is true? What was the source of inspiration? That is the necessary information (context) that you need to add.

@Mari-LouA My question is simple. I don't know who 'her' is in the given sentence. That's why I asked this question as FumbleFingers commented earlier. No context.

OK, where did you find this sentence? That information is also context. And if you made it up, you should say this, that too is context. P.S Two users have cast votes to close this question. Maybe the edit is sufficient to keep the question but maybe not.

In a dictionary as an example sentence. Over.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illusion

@ishtar well, look at the original post, two users cast their votes to close the question. Contextless questions are frustrating to answer because the answer is nearly always it depends  and without the edits, I would probably have  cast my off-topic vote too. For me, the decisive question is whether the reflexive pronoun, "herself", that the OP suggests,  fits,  appropriate, (un)grammatical or redundant. Now the question is more interesting but also  useful to more learners and visitors.

" ... that John is in love with herself" is ungrammatical.

The sentence does not say that John is in love with anybody. It says that Jane believes wrongly that John is in love with her. John may be in love with another woman, another man, himself, or perhaps nobody at all. The only thing we know about John is that he is not in love with Jane.
The sentence is simple enough to be understood fairly easily, and a native English speaker would not misunderstand it unless they were distracted or misheard it.

Suppose the sentence was preceded by one saying 'John seems to be always looking at Mary.'?

@MichaelHarvey, adding only that context would make it possible that Mary is the woman with whom John is not in love. Further context would be needed to decide whether it is Jane or Mary.

John might not even exist.

@TimR, True. Of course a non-existent person cannot be in love with anybody.

As is often the case, you need to know the context to interpret the statement.
"John is polite to Jane and wants to be her friend. But Jane has this illusion that John is in love with her."
"Her" refers to Jane. Jane thinks that John is in love with Jane.
"John follows Mary around everywhere, because he thinks that she can and will help him get a promotion at work. But Jane misinterprets John's actions and thinks John has feelings for Mary. Jane has this illusion that John is in love with her."
"Her" refers to Mary. Jane thinks that John is in love with Mary.
